# Contracting tensors using diffgeo

Tags: physics, tensors

I am trying to understand the way [diffgeo](http://people.brandeis.edu/~headrick/Mathematica/) does contractions, so I can get a result that makes sense.

I am using the following example:

$g_{ab}g_{cd}A^{abcd}$,

where $g_{ab}$ is the metric and $A^{abd}$ is a generic tensor. Now, to use `Contract` in diffgeo, all indices have to be lower. Does this mean that the following would give the correct contraction?

```
Contract[metric**metric**lower[A]]
```

Another example is when contracting the Riemann tensor, which in diffgeo is defined as $R_{abc}$$^d$. So I assume that contracting this: $R_{abcd}A^{abcd}$ would mean I have to write:

```
Contract[lower[Riemann, {4}]**lower[A]]
```

Can anyone advise? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are asking about third-party packages, please link to them.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!